# How do I modify a QLabel object in my UI outside of its slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel

Just a short question:

I wish to edit the text of a QLabel object outside of its slot, depending on the value of a conditional statement unrelated to the widget. Research online has been inconclusive, so I would greatly appreciate if any of you could clarify how this is done.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I used Qt Designer to put the QLabel in my MainWindow class, meaning it was never formally declared within my MainWindow.cpp source code. Here is an explanation with code:

```
if (webcam.isOpened() == false)
{
    MainWindow::mainVideo.setText("Stream is offline.")
    /*mainVideo is my QLabel, I need to figure out how to access this if
     *it was placed into my UI via Qt Designer.
     */
}
```

Comment: What is the condition for you to modify the QLabel?

Comment: Besides it is not necessary to have a slot to modify its value

Comment: It's just a boolean value. If a video stream is detected (I'm working with OpenCV), display video stream and make the text within the QLabel blank. If it isn't detected, display "Video Stream Offline" in bold, red letters, with center justification.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Qt, how could I modify its value without its slot?

Comment: use: if(condition){yourlabel.setText(your text);}

Comment: It would be good if you put your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be use:

```
if(condition){yourlabel.setText(your text);}
```

In your case:

```
if (!webcam.isOpened())
{
    ui->mainVideo->setText("Stream is offline.")
    /*mainVideo is my QLabel, I need to figure out how to access this if
     *it was placed into my UI via Qt Designer.
     */
}
```

Comment: I used Qt Designer to put the QLabel within my UI, it was never explicitly declared in my .cpp file. Therefore, following that suggestion leads to compile-time errors. I probably should have stated that in my original question, let me revise it along with some code.

Comment: @MichaelLilley ui->label->setText("your text");